# Not all code paths return a value, but it seems they do

Tags: typescript, for-loop

I'm trying to iterate an array of a custom class I've made, but it's tell me not all code paths return a value. In Java, most certainly all paths return a value.

```
function PointLiesWithinAtleast1Polygon(point: CLLocationCoordinate2D, polygons: Array<GMSPath>){

polygons.forEach(polygon =>{
    if(GMSGeometryContainsLocation(point, polygon)){
        return true;
    }
});

return false;

}
```

The polygons array is iterated and if the conditions are met then it returns true and the function is ended. If the condition isn't met then the loop breaks and returns false. Why is it saying not all code paths return a value?

Comment: The method `PointLiesWithinAtleast1Polygon` always return `false`. When you do `return true;` in your lambda function, you're exiting the lambda and returning in the `PointLiesWithinAtleast1Polygon` function.

Comment: @Marco Oh, I need to define a bool outside of the anonymous function. Thanks!

Comment: You can use a regular for-in loop instead of a forEach lambda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `PointLiesWithinAtleast1Polygon` always return `false`. When you do `return true;` in your lambda function, you're exiting the lambda and returning in the `PointLiesWithinAtleast1Polygon` function.

Java version

```java
function PointLiesWithinAtleast1Polygon(point: CLLocationCoordinate2D, polygons: Array<GMSPath>){
    for (GMSPath polygon : polygons) 
    { 
        if(!GMSGeometryContainsLocation(point, polygon)){
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Like you said in the comment, you can either define a boolean outside the anonymous function, or you can use normal `for loop` and check if the criteria isn't met.

In Typescript, you can use the `every` method of `Array` to check that every object has a certain criteria.

```js
function PointLiesWithinAtleast1Polygon(point: CLLocationCoordinate2D, polygons: Array<GMSPath>){
    return polygons.every((polygon: GMSPath) =>{
        return GMSGeometryContainsLocation(point, polygon);
    });
}
```

Comment: Before I accept your answer, I must point out that typescript doesn't allow this syntax for a for loop. This looks more like Java.

Comment: My bad, I haven't checked the tags of your question. I updated my answer to include an example for typescript. In case someone has the same problem but in Java, I don't remove the Java's example. In typescript there is the `every` method of `Array`, it will do exactly what you want ;)

Comment: Thanks. I did not know about the every function. I learn something new all the time on here. Thanks!